# How to structure video input for LSTM with keras?

Tags: video, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, vgg-net

I have each frame from multiple videos and their labels in batches - with the use of data generator.

I want to get each frame's CNN features (say VGG) and use them as input to an LSTM (pretty classic).

I understand the concept of the sliding window and step size, but what I don't understand is how do we structure the video in a way that it is aware when a video ends and another begins? In the few examples I could find this is never mentioned and the sliding window is run sequentially on a batch, meaning that it will have windows of one video ending and another beginning as if they are consequent. Putting each video in a batch and padding them is not feasible because 1. The video sizes differ greatly 2. Most videos are longer than batch size.

Another thing I can not get my head around is, all examples focus on predicting the next frame but isn't there a way to do classification directly? Predicting the next frame after 5 frames is a different problem than classifying a sequence of frames, I would think time smoothing or averaging could be an option but is there a better way?).

Thanks.